# TYPO3 RealURL postVarSets hide keyword

Tags: typo3, realurl

I have an URL which looks like this:

```
http://domain.com/leistungen/industrial-design/?tx_fsproject_fsprojectfp%5Bproject%5D=2&tx_fsproject_fsprojectfp%5Baction%5D=show&tx_fsproject_fsprojectfp%5Bcontroller%5D=Project&cHash=7c405bcde49853af9a7e78bdf465002c
```

Using RealURL with the following configuration (and some hook functions as explained [here](http://www.t3node.com/blog/hiding-repeated-segments-with-realurl/)):

```
'postVarSets' => array(
        '_DEFAULT' => array(
            // projects
            'industrial-design' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_fsproject_fsprojectfp[controller]',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_fsproject_fsprojectfp[action]',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_fsproject_fsprojectfp[project]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_fsproject_domain_model_project',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND deleted !=1 AND hidden !=1',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                            'strtolower' => 1,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                        )
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

I get an URL looking like this:

```
http://domain.com/leistungen/industrial-design/industrial-design/projekt/project-b/
```

This is not bad. However, why does the `industrial-design/` part show up twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first *industrial-design* is the page that is being displayed. The second one is the keyword inserted by RealURL to identify the set of variables. To avoid that you can:

1. Change the structure of pages so that you don't have *industrial-design* page at all.
2. Rename the `postVarSets` that you set up in the RealURL configuration.
3. Use `fixedPostVars` instead as that doesn't use a keyword to identify the set of variables but a page UID.

Comment: `fixedPostVarSets` did the job. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: I'm curious… I can't find documentation on `fixedPostVarSets` or how to use it. All the examples online only have it as an empty array. If you Google for it you only find this post here. Is it used like `postVarSets` with a page ID instead of `_DEFAULT`, or a page ID instead of the postVar keyword?

Comment: @slhck: S***! I'm sorry. I now realized that it should be `fixedPostVars`. When writing my answer I mistyped it due to the RealURL's mixed naming: `postVarSets` VS `preVars`, `fixedPostVars`. I can't believe this mistake stayed in the answer for so long. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Haha, great, thanks for correcting this! I was just incredibly confused—although this time TYPO3 wasn't the source of confusion :)